# Ruby OpenSSL changing the block-size

Tags: ruby, openssl, rijndael

Is it at all possible in OpenSSL to change the block size? I am using Ruby and from what I can tell there is no way to do this.

I just want to confirm this is true. Here is a link to the only method I can find related to block size which just returns what the block size is. https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html#method-i-block_size but other than that I don't see a way to do this. Is it possible? I know I can set the key size but not the block size. It seems it is stuck with a 128-bit block size?

Specifically I want to use AES which I understand is only a 128-bit block size. But Rijndael which is what AES is based on can be set up to a 256-bit block size so I was wondering if OpenSSL would allow me to set the block size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

- [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard), as standardized by NIST, is a subset of the Rijndael cipher family.  While Rijndael supports several different block and key sizes, AES is only defined to use a block size of 128 bits and a key size of either 128, 192 or 256 bits.
- The list of [ciphers supported by OpenSSL](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/tree/master/crypto) only includes AES, not Rijndael.
- The OpenSSL AES implementation is [hardcoded to use a block size of 16 bytes](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/48f4ad7718498577af52878b9e8b0924d8faf83f/include/openssl/aes.h#L28) (= 128 bits).

Short of adding Rijndael [as a new cipher to OpenSSL](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/How_to_Integrate_a_Symmetric_Cipher) and rebuilding the library yourself, you will not be able to use OpenSSL to encrypt or decrypt data using any of the Rijndael variants other than those standardized as AES.